# Refactor code without goto

Tags: c++, refactoring, goto

I'm little confused. How this statement can be refactored without `goto`?

```
if(first_expression)
{
    // ....
    if(second_expression)
    {
        // ....
    }
    else
    {
        goto jump_out;
    }
}
else
{
    jump_out:
    // ....
}
```

Is this good way?

```
bool expressionFailed = false;
if(first_expression)
{
    if(second_expression)
    {
        // ....
    }
    else
        expressionsFailed = true;
}
else
    expressionsFailed = true;

if(expressionsFailed)
{
    // ....
}
```

I can not use `&&`, because code after `if(first_expression)` need to be executed when `second_expression = false`

Comment: Yes, that looks okay.

Comment: The code you have written is fine

Comment: Use break instead of goto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. I would simplify it to:

```
bool succeeded = false;
if(first_expression)
{
    if(second_expression)
    {
       succeeded = true;
       // ....
    }
}

if(!succeeded)
{
   // ....
}
```

Comment: It is best case for me

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about your code but you could do this:

```
void on_error ()
{
  //error stuff
}

int main ()
{
    if(first_expression)
    {
        if(second_expression)
        {
            // ....
        }
        else
            on_error();
    }
    else
        on_error();
}
```

or even better:

```
void job()
{
    if(first_expression)
    {
        if(second_expression)
        {
            // ....
        }
        else
            throw;
    }
    else
        throw;
}

int main () {
  try
  {
    job();
  }
  catch ()
  {
    // err stuff 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it as follows:

```
if(first_expression)
{
    // ....
    if(second_expression)
    {
        // ....
    }
}
if(!first_expression || (first_expression && !second_expression))
{
}
```